# SQL subquery , using WHERE & 'IN' to filter for specific rows

Tags: mysql, sql

please use [here](http://sqlfiddle.com) and copy the code in below to add context to my questions.

As you see, I have a table and within it certain Father's have the same name, I want to choose the `father` that has the most `dogs` for my final list. You can see the entire table in `Query #1` , my desired result in `Query #2` with respect to `Father's` returned, but when I am trying to get Father `John` in `Query #3` to only return 1 time but it shows the entire record for Father John with 9 dogs and 10 dogs.

How can I get `Query #3` to select only one Father whom has the Max Dogs, and return the rest of the columns as well?

Create tables code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_3` 
(
    `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `Father` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `Dogs` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `table_3` (`id`,`Father`, `Dogs`) 
VALUES ('1', 'John', '10'),
       ('2', 'John','9'),
       ('3', 'Joe', '4'),
       ('4', 'Jeremy', '4'),
       ('5', 'Jack', '4'),
       ('6', 'NULL', '5');
```

Query #1

```
select Father from table_3;
```

Query #1 OUTPUT:

```
id  Father  Dogs
1   John    10
2   John    9
3   Joe 4
4   Jeremy  4
5   Jack    4
6   NULL    5
```

Query #2

```
select b.Father from (select Father, max(Dogs)
from table_3
group by 1
)b;
```

Query #2 OUTPUT

```
Father
Jack
Jeremy
Joe
John
NULL
```

Query #3

```
select * from table_3 a
where a.Father in (
select b.Father from (select Father, max(Dogs)
from table_3 
group by 1
)b);
```

Query #3 Output

```
id  Father  Dogs
1   John    10
2   John    9
3   Joe 4
4   Jeremy  4
5   Jack    4
6   NULL    5
```

Desired Output from Query #3

```
id  Father  Dogs
1   John    10

3   Joe 4
4   Jeremy  4
5   Jack    4
6   NULL    5
```

Comment: please tag appropriate database.

Comment: @mkRabbani not sure what you mean, appreciate the feedback tho

Comment: Which database you are using? like - MySQL, SQLSERVER, Oracle?

Comment: oh gotha, thanks for clarity - mysql 5.6, but that is just within the sql fiddle env. I will eventually be using it in Snowflake.

Comment: Query #1 OUTPUT is wrong. Should only have the `Father` column, not all 3 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
SELECT * FROM table_3 A
INNER JOIN( 
    SELECT father,MAX(Dogs) Dogs 
    -- You need to CAST your Dogs column to INT before you apply MAX on this column
    FROM table_3
    GROUP BY Father
)B
ON A.father = B.father
AND A.Dogs = B.Dogs
```

You can also try with row number if your database permits as below-

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY father ORDER BY Dogs DESC) RN
    FROM table_3
) A WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for response , but I do not think joining on Father is a good idea, as it is not a surrogate key, This is a simple example using basic data so I do not think this would scale.

Comment: Query logic is also for your reference only. You can try your way with this logic as per your requirement and data structure. Check the output here- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f64f1d/4

Comment: Why Dogs field is varchar? This will not return your expected MAX number.

Comment: *FYI:* MySQL 5.6 doesn't support `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ...)`, need [MySQL 8.0 for that](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number), however [Snowflake does](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html).

Comment: Yes, you can go for the first option.

Answer (score 0):

use this..

```
select * from table_3 group by Father order by Dogs
```

or

```
SELECT id, Father, max(CONVERT(Dogs,SIGNED)) from table_3 group by Father
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code can help you in sql server:

```
SELECT Father,
   MAX(CONVERT(INT, Dogs))
FROM   table_3
GROUP BY
   father
ORDER BY
   MAX(CONVERT(INT, Dogs)) DESC
```

Or

```
SELECT DISTINCT Father,
   MAX(CONVERT(INT, Dogs)) OVER(PARTITION BY Father) AS avgsales
FROM   table_3
```

in Mysql

change:

```
CONVERT(INT, Dogs)
```

to

```
CAST(Dogs AS SIGNED)
```